# shapely and geos break in distance method

Tags: python, geos, shapely

I'm having problems using the distance method in shapely (I suspect incompatibility with the geos package).

The following code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
print Point(0,0).distance(Point(1,1))
```

creates the following error:

```
python: GeometryComponentFilter.cpp:34: virtual void geos::geom::GeometryComponentFilter::filter_ro(const geos::geom::Geometry*): Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I’m running CentOS 6, python 2.6, geos 3.4.2 (although it creates a link from libgeos_c to 1.8.2)

Googling it yielded a few old posts which didn't really help me.

Thanks,
Raz

Comment: How did you install GEOS and Shapely?

Comment: shapely using pip, GEOS by downloading the zip file, doing configure, make, and make install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a GEOS bug ([#535](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/535)). As a work around, try fetching a development snapshot [that appears to solve this issue](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/changeset/3960):

```
svn co http://svn.osgeo.org/geos/trunk@3960 geos-svn
cd geos-svn
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
```

If the last command throws any similar errors, consider contributing feedback to the bug report. But if all is good, then it should be good for shapely. As root:

```
make install
ldconfig
```

Comment: Thanks. The make check didn't throw any similar error (BTW, I did configure --enable-python). However, the installed version still has the same problem. The time stamp on libgeos_c seems recent, so I hope I'm really using the latest library.

Comment: Try as root `ldconfig` to ensure the dynamic library links are up-to-date. I have a feeling that it is still linking to an older broken build. Also, `--enable-python` has not been supported directly through GEOS for a very long time.

Comment: ldconfig /usr/local/lib solved the problem. Thanks! when not using --enable-python, the configure says: Python bindings: false. Is this good?

Comment: Yeah, the Python bindings have never really been supported directly from GEOS. Shapely uses the C-API.